# I can't get data of my table with bootstrap pagination with vueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show from my api using pagination on a table with filtered data. When I put the function in methods, I get the data from (event-1), but I when I put the function of items in computed I don't get an array of data but an object. So, my data can't be showed. Please how can I get the data please?

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control search ml-4 mb-4" placeholder="search" v-model="filterNameInput" :onChange="filterByName">

<b-table hover responsive="sm" :busy.sync="isBusy" :sort-by.sync="sortBy" :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc" :items="fetchPlaces" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage" @row-clicked="rowClickHandler">

  <template slot="created" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.created | moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") }}
  </template>
  <template slot="updated" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.updated | moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") }}
  </template>
  <template slot="categories" slot-scope="data">
    <b-badge v-for="category in data.item.categories" :key="category.id" variant="primary">{{category.name}}</b-badge>
  </template>

</b-table>
```

```js
computed: {
  fetchPlaces(ctx) {
    let params = '?apikey=apiKey&lng=en&page=' + ctx.currentPage + '&limit=' + ctx.perPage
    if (this.sortBy) {
      params += '&sort=' + this.sortBy
      if (this.sortDesc) {
        params += '&dir=DESC'
      }
    }
    if (this.filterStatus !== '' || this.filterNameInput !== '') {
      params += '&sort=name&dir=ASC'
      if (this.filterStatus !== '') {
        params += '&filter[status]=like|' + this.filterStatus
      }
      console.log(this.filterNameInput)
      if (this.filterNameInput !== '') {
        params += '&filter[name]=%like%|' + this.filterNameInput
      }
    }
    let promise = this.$http.get(apiUrl + params)

    return promise.then((data) => {
      let items = data.body.data
      this.totalRows = data.body.totalItems
      return (items || [])
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computed is returning a `Promise`, not a value. Also, computeds (in their simple form) are like getters, they don't take arguments.

The proper place to make asynchronous computations is in watchers:

- Create a computed that calculates `params` (which will recalculate every time a "part" of `params` changes).
- Create a watcher for `params` to trigger the API call with the new `params` and update the data field `fetchPlaces`
- Use `fetchPlaces` in the template, which will be updated asynchronously automatically when the API call returns.

Here's the suggested resulting code:

```html
<b-table ... :items="fetchPlaces" ... >
```

```js
data() {
  // properties used somewhere in the code below (types may differ)
  apiUrl: 'http://api.example.com',
  currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 1,
  sortBy: 'somefield',
  sortDesc: false,
  filterStatus: 1,
  filterNameInput: 'someinput',
  totalRows: 0,
  fetchPlaces: [],
},
computed: {
  params() {
    let params = '?apikey=apiKey&lng=en&page=' + this.currentPage + '&limit=' + this.perPage
    if (this.sortBy) {
      params += '&sort=' + this.sortBy
      if (this.sortDesc) {
        params += '&dir=DESC'
      }
    }
    if (this.filterStatus !== '' || this.filterNameInput !== '') {
      params += '&sort=name&dir=ASC'
      if (this.filterStatus !== '') {
        params += '&filter[status]=like|' + this.filterStatus
      }
      console.log(this.filterNameInput)
      if (this.filterNameInput !== '') {
        params += '&filter[name]=%like%|' + this.filterNameInput
      }
    }
    return params;
  }
},
watch: {
  params(newParams, oldParams) {
    this.updateFetchPlaces(newParams);
  }
},
methods: {
  updateFetchPlaces(newParams) {
    this.$http.get(this.apiUrl + newParams).then((data) => {
      let items = data.body.data

      this.totalRows = data.body.totalItems
      this.fetchPlaces = items || [];
    });
  }
},
created() {
  this.updateFetchPlaces(this.params); // initial fetch
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the pagination isn't working. The data is shown only in the first page.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log` in the watcher `params(oldParams, newParams) { console.log('going to fetch for:', newParams); ...` to check if it is being called?

Comment: the console.log is not called when l load page.

Comment: Oh, I see. The initial loading. Just a moment.

Comment: I moved the fetching to a method that is called on the watcher. And now it is called on `created()` to perform the initial lading.

Comment: Thank for your answer but the pagination still not working. If I want to show the data of a page, I have to click on the number of the page and after click on the first page to see the data. How can I solve the pagination please.

Comment: Do you get an error? In my answer there are several properties in the `data`, do you have all of them? If you haven't then it won't work.

Comment: I have no errors. I have those properties on data. I put console .log(this.fetchPlaces) and I get the data and also for this.currentPage. But I get those data only in the first page not in the corresponding page.

Comment: Can you expand your code? Show the complete instance, with `data` and such.

Comment: I added it as Answer 2.

Comment: In your `watch` the params are flipped. The correct is `params (oldParams, newParams) {`

Comment: Yes I flipped them because because when I put the console. log the old param was the new and vice-versa.
For the pagination, even the method that shows the data, the pagination isn't working

Comment: I add a ref to <b-table ref="place"> and I call a refresh on params function in watch :
this.$refs.places_table.refresh()
It works now, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Y.Coding, could you provide the code for this? You mention `place` then `places_table`. Also, when I've tried doing this, I get an "undefined" error.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Sorry I made  a mistake, it's only place.You have to put the name of the reference. so it's:<b-table ref="place">  and  this.$refs.place.refresh()

Comment: @acdcjunior `params (oldParams, newParams) {` only the opposite one is working in my end...what is wrong here?

Comment: @AakashBashyal The new value (if you mean the old value by "opposite") must be being set to `undefined`, then, right?

Comment: @acdcjunior,  if I changed this method parameter `params (oldParams, newParams)`  to `params (newParams, oldParams)`, only then I get the updated value on `newParamas`. the oldParams will have the old value. No, it is not undefined. both will have the value. i do have to flip the parameter, to make this work.

Comment: @AakashBashyal oops, you are right, it is a typo(?) in the answer. The correct order is `new, old`!

Answer (score 0):

```
             <v-select class="my-4 dropdownHashgroup" v-model="filterStatus" :onChange="statusOnChange" :options="placeStatus" label="label" placeholder="Status"></v-select>
             <input type="text" class="form-control search ml-4 mb-4" placeholder="search" v-model="filterNameInput" :onChange="filterByName">

             <b-table hover responsive="sm" :busy.sync="isBusy" :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
                             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc" :items="fetchPlaces" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage" @row-clicked="rowClickHandler">
                          </b-table>
        import vSelect from 'vue-select'

          export default {
            name: 'grid-places',
            data: () => {
              return {
                apiUrl: 'apiUrl',
                apiKey: 'apiKey',
                isBusy: false,
                fields: [
                  { key: 'name', sortable: true },
                  { key: 'created', sortable: true },
                  { key: 'updated', sortable: true },
                  { key: 'score' },
                  { key: 'categories' }
                ],
                currentPage: 1,
                perPage: 10,
                totalRows: 0,
                sortBy: 'name',
                sortDesc: false,
                placeStatus: ['DRAFT', 'PUBLISHED', 'DISABLED'],
                filterStatus: 'PUBLISHED',
                filterNameInput: '',
                fetchPlaces: []
              }
            },
        methods: {
              updateFetchPlaces (newParams) {
                this.$http.get(this.apiUrl + newParams).then((data) => {
                  let items = data.body.data
                  this.totalRows = data.body.totalItems
                  this.fetchPlaces = items || []
                })
              },
            },
        computed: {
           params () {
            let params = '?apikey=' + this.apiKey + '&lng=en&page=' + this.currentPage + '&limit=' + this.perPage
            if (this.sortBy) {
              params += '&sort=' + this.sortBy
              if (this.sortDesc) {
                params += '&dir=DESC'
              }
            }
            if (this.filterStatus !== '' || this.filterNameInput !== '') {
              params += '&sort=name&dir=ASC'
            }
            if (this.filterStatus !== '' && this.filterNameInput === '') {
              params += '&filter[status]=like|' + this.filterStatus
            }
            if (this.filterNameInput !== '' && this.filterStatus === '') {
              params += '&filter[name]=%like%|' + this.filterNameInput
            }
            return params
          },
          statusOnChange () {
          },
          filterByName () {
          }
    },
    watch: {
      params (newParams, oldParams) {
        console.log('going to fetch for:', newParams)
        this.$http.get(this.apiUrl + newParams).then((data) => {
          let items = data.body.data
          this.totalRows = data.body.totalItems
          this.fetchPlaces = items || []
          console.log(this.fetchPlaces)
          console.log(this.currentPage)
        })
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.updateFetchPlaces(this.params)
    },
    components: {
      vSelect
    }
```